# Octave boxplot grouping variable

Tags: octave, boxplot

Thank you in advance for your help !

In Matlab, the [boxplot command](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/boxplot.html) can accept the grouping variable G, which is:

> boxplot(X,G) specifies one or more grouping variables G, producing a separate box for each set of X values sharing the same G value or values. Grouping variables must have one row per element of X, or one row per column of X. Specify a single grouping variable in G using a vector, a character array, a cell array of strings, or a vector categorical array; specify multiple grouping variables in G using a cell array of these variable types, such as {G1 G2 G3}, or by using a matrix. If multiple grouping variables are used, they must all be the same length. Groups that contain a NaN value or an empty string in a grouping variable are omitted, and are not counted in the number of groups considered by other parameters.

However, this parameter seems to be missing from the Octave implementation of boxplot. For example, suppose I have the following vectors,

X = [1.34, 2.89, 1.28, 2.98, 8.84, 8.38, 3.26, 4.06, 42.48, 3.19, 3.63, 3.23 ]; % a lot longer

G = [1, 3, 3, 3, 23, 15, 15, 23, 23, 20, 23, 23 ]; % a lot longer

Running boxplot(X, G) in matlab will create a plot where values in X (in the same group) are put together into the same box.

Is there any way to workaround this in Octave ?

Comment: If you run `which boxplot` it will show you the path for the `boxplot.m` file. Open it in your text editor and try to fix it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Octave boxplot allows using as input a cell vector.
You can previously create the cell vector as follows.

```
uniG = unique(G);
l = length(uniG);
for i = 1:l
  XG{i} = X(G == uniG(i));
end
boxplot(XG);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must group them in a cell as mentioned by Santiago, but it can be done easier by

`boxplot({X, G})`

See example in http://octave.sourceforge.net/statistics/function/boxplot.html, pay attention to *{* and *}*.